# I added an image to the body element as background. But when there is autoflow, the picture does not fit properly

Tags: css

My code;

```
        body {
            background: url("<?= PUBLIC_URL ?>img/background_image.jpg") no-repeat center/cover;
            height: 100%;
            autoflow: hidden;
        }
        .container {
            width: 1400px;
            max-width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
            height: 100vh;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
```

The image that appears when I open the browser fits perfectly.
But when the size of the page is larger, when you scroll down, the image does not appear, a white area appears, that is, empty space.

How can I make this image fully responsive? I want it to fit completely into the background no matter the browser size.

Comment: Can you create a runnable snippet which demonstrates the problem. At the moment I don’t understand your full requirement because you have given the elements max height of viewport height. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It actually centers the picture. No problem with it. But when I add new html element on body this problem happens. The page is moving down. The page stretches down due to the data on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the CSS property on the container div

```
.container{
   ...
   height: 100vh; // what if the content overflows
   ...
}
```

is causing the main problem, because if your content inside the container div overflows, the page will scroll but to the body the height of the container is fixed ie.100vh so it will not resize the background image.

to fix this issue you must remove this line of code in order to let the container resize based on the content inside and in turn let the background image resize.

but if the div is shorter than the viewport height the background image will shrink too, so you need to add min-height property to the body element like so:

```
body{
   ...
   min-height: 100vh;
   ...
}
```

remember if you add a lot of content to the page it will cause the background image to zoom in to the center in order to cover whole document and get pixelated, if you want the background image to be fixed while allowing page content to scroll above it you can use background-attachment property on the body element like so:

```
body{
   ...
   background-attachment: fixed;
   ...
}
```

btw, I don't think there's any property called autoflow in CSS, correct me if I am wrong,

hope this solves your issue

Comment: If you go the background-attachment: fixed route be aware that at the current time IOS Safari has a bug, see https://caniuse.com/?search=background-attachment. You will have to put the background onto a before pseudo element instead.

Comment: This solved my problem. It would be "overflow" not "autoflow", I spelled it wrong :) Thanks all.